# How could I determine what type python cast to?

Tags: python

is it always casting result to float if there is one( or more ) element in calculation?

for example:

```
1*1.0  # float 
from   fractions        import Fraction
Fraction(1) * 1.0   # float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it does always cast to float if one of arguments is float,  because float is most common number type. So if you do some operation (multiplication in your case) with float and other number interpreter can be sure it's posible to convert other number to float (doesn't mater is it int, Fraction or even Bool) without losing any information, but it can't do it other way around.

Here is link (https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesnumeric.html) 
It suggests obvious thing i forgot. Complex numbers are more commont than Float. So if you will try to multiply float to complex. you will get complex.

"Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the ``narrower'' type is widened to that of the other, where plain integer is narrower than long integer is narrower than floating point is narrower than complex. Comparisons between numbers of mixed type use the same rule."

Comment: thank you for the answer. I wonder if  you can point me to any related documents. thank you

Comment: Edited an answer, providing link and quote

Answer (score -1):

No, it works because the Fraction class implements a `__mul__` (and probably `__rmul__`) method used to define the result of a multiplication with an other object (a float in your case).

That's called operator overloading.

EDIT: I don't understand why I got downvoted. According to your example, the answer is **No, you don't always get a float, it depends of the other object**.

For example, you can see in the Python Fraction source code the implementation of `__mul__` and `__rmul__` : https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/fractions.py#l421 and the function which does the computing : https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/fractions.py#l377 .